# How to align fancy footer and header with text?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I use `fancyhdr` for customized headers/footers. I have the following code :

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\fancyhead{} 
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyheadoffset[L]{\dimexpr\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}
\fancyhead[LE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{|\quad\thepage\quad |}
```

Before I added this :

```
\fancyheadoffset[L]{\dimexpr\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}
```

Each the headers/footers dont align with my text.I have a twosided `scrreprt`.
What i want to achieve is that on odd page numbers the header should align left and even page numbers on the right.And the same for the footer.Like this :
[image]

When

```
 \fancyheadoffset[L]{\dimexpr\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}
```

is added, the footers seems to be ok (WHY ?) and on even page numbers also, but on odd page numbers it is not aligned.
Like this :
[image]

Comment: Are you loading [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) perhaps? If so, you need to load `geometry` *before* [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr). However, you're using [KOMA-script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script), which has its own header-setting options...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Since you're using `scrreprt`: KOMA classes and `fancyhdr` may work together, but often they are conflicting!

Comment: @Werner yes i load geometry before fancyhdr

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Ok good to know,i will try another class

Comment: @lolio: Alright. If that does not work as desired come back please and provide a compilable document that shows the issues.

Comment: I got it to work with book class using \fancyheadoffset[LE,RO]{-1in}  The offset is in addition to the margins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding this :

```
 \fancyheadoffset[L]{0pt}
```

Comment: Given that this is the default value, you could equally well not set an offset at all.

Comment: Well then it is not aligned...strange

Comment: Without a minimal example we can use to reproduce the issue, it is hard to say why, but zero is the default so something is misaligning things and then you are using this to get back to the default aligned configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting answer above. I have a similar problem with an unintentional rightshift on right justified header text on odd pages only. I solved it with:

```
\fancyheadoffset[RO]{0pt}
```

But this seems to imply there is a bug still in `fancyhdr` Version 4. My example is complex with different page formatting for right and left pages that contain several tables per page. (I use MiKTeX on Windows with all current updates and I installed fancyhdr yesterday.)